# How to change fontsize on drawText?

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString str = QString::number((double)i, 'd', 1);
painter->drawText(100 + i * 800/9 - 6, 910, 40, 40, 0, str );
```

I would like to increase fontSize to 2x what is showing?

Answer (score 30):

You could try something like this (haven't compiled code to see if it works!):

```
QFont font = painter->font() ;

/* twice the size than the current font size */
font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() * 2);

/* set the modified font to the painter */
painter->setFont(font);

/* draw text etc. */
painter.drawText(....);
```

Comment: well, back in 2013 it was `getPointSize` :D

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out:

```
QFont font;
font.setPixelSize(12);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    painter->drawLine(100, 100 + i * 800/9, 900, 100 + i * 800/9);
    str = QString::number((double)9 - i, 'd', 1);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->drawText(75, 100 + i * 800/9 - 6, 40, 40, 1, str);
}
```

Comment: if you have a font **different than the default**, it will probably reset it instead of just modifying its size.

Answer (score 3):

this is the easiest way

```
painter.setFont(QFont("times",22)); //22 is a number which you have to change
```